# Django Model JSON

Tags: json, сериализация, django-model

Прошу подскажите как должна выглядеть модель django если у меня есть вид того, в каком виде получаются данные в формате JSON:

```
  values {
  "firstname": "l",
  "lastname": "m",
  "links": [
    {
      "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
      "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
    },
    {
      "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
      "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
    }
  ]
  }
```

То есть, как видно из примера, таких Links может быть сколько угодно (это динамическая вложенная форма).

Вот таким вот образом значит(как представлено ниже) отправляю это все на сервер (api rest framework):

```
 onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
             await axios ({
             method: 'post',
             url: 'http://localhost:8000/something/',
             data: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
           })
        }}
```

Можете подсказать как это на сервере в моделях django и сериализаторе организовать так, чтобы все корректно сохранялось в бд.

Заранее благодарю кто поможет